# How do I use that "<<<HTML" thing in PHP?

Tags: php

I know I shouldn't be outputting things directly in PHP, but using a template instead, but whatever.

I remember perl being able to do this, and as I reached for my perl book, I realized: I already packed it, as I'm moving. It's incredibly difficult to search for "<<<", as well.

So, I know I can go,

```
echo <<<SOMESTUFF
blah
blah
blah
```

but other than that I'm at a loss... How do I end it? Where do I need semicolons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, this syntax is called a [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). The linked documentation contains some helpful examples.

Answer (score 0):

To end it, type:

```
echo <<<SOMESTUFF
...
SOMESTUFF
```

With `SOMESTUFF` being on a line of its own. See the PHP manual on "heredocs" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), and allows you to define long strings, without having to care about escaping double-quotes *(nor single, btw)*

Syntax goes like this :

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Note this (quoting the doc) :

> A third way to delimit strings is the
>   heredoc syntax: <<<. After this
>   operator, an identifier is provided,
>   then a newline. The string itself
>   follows, and then the same identifier
>   again to close the quotation.
>
> The closing identifier must begin in
>   the first column of the line. Also,
>   the identifier must follow the same
>   naming rules as any other label in
>   PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric
>   characters and underscores, and must
>   start with a non-digit character or
>   underscore.

And also note it is not exactly the same as [nowdoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which only exists since PHP >= 5.3