# What is this in PHP? Multiple code for one variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I use that “<<<HTML” thing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203479/how-do-i-use-that-html-thing-in-php)
>   [PHP <<<EOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048481/php-eob)

```
   $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
    title VARCHAR(150),
    bodytext  TEXT,
    created VARCHAR(100)
  )
  MySQL_QUERY;
```

I've seen people use the above to include multiple lines of string and set it to a variable,  was wondering if there is a name for this kind of use? So that I can look it up.

Comment: Dupe at least a few times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048481/php-eob
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571894/how-do-i-write-the-toc-thing-in-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040578/how-do-i-write-this-out-in-php-where-i-would-use-the-to-print-out-content
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203479/how-do-i-use-that-html-thing-in-php

Comment: It is a dupe, but dupes are hard to find if you don't know to search for 'heredoc'.

Comment: @Tom Haigh - good point, do you think questions like 'what the heck is this syntax' should be exceptions to the dupe rule?

Comment: @karim79 maybe, or maybe there could be a search that would let you search for a set of characters like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> 

A third way to delimit [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)s is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

> 

The closing identifier *must* begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

> > 

**Warning** It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier *may not be indented*, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is *\n* on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

> > 

If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.

> > 

Heredocs can not be used for initializing class properties. Since PHP 5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables...

Comment: Paolo did winned the fight again, but this is a dupe's dupe dupe.

Comment: Oo, shame on me. I even answered one of the dupes! :(

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino - I would've answered this too, I'm just being a sore loser :(